# How do I display a 2D-array value from C# to a View?

Tags: c#, razor, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array in C#

```
public class DBResult
{
   public string[,] dbDataArray = new string[100, 100];
}
```

How do I display the value of a cell in a View using Razor ?

I do this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.dbDataArray[0,0])
```

but I get the following error
"Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@model string[,]

<table>
@for (int row = 0; row < Model.GetUpperBound(0); row++)
{
    <tr>
    @for (int column = 0; column < Model.GetUpperBound(1); column++)
    {
        <td>@Model[row, column]</td>
    }
    </tr>
}
</table>
```